# Unable to view foreign keys in SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms, heidisql

I am having issues with importing data into SQL using HeidiSQL. I have a really basic table that looks like so:

[image]

It has an Index on it that looks like so:

[image]

For some reason in HeidiSQL I cannot look at the Foreign Key tab:

[image]

But then I have no issue looking/creating these in SSMS:

[image]

HeidiSQL seems to get confused and will not let me look at the Foreign Key tab however SSMS has no such issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like HeidiSQL doesn't support a few aspects of foreign keys when using Azure SQL; this guy was complaining about it two years ago: https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=19139

[image]

Note the exact same error message as shown in your HS screenshot..

Kinda disappointing that it's been an issue for so long!

Comment: Damn that is a shame as SSMS really isn't great... may have to use a mixture of the two for now then!